# how does requirejs recognize modules that gets loaded before loading require js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

Am new in using require JS Framework . Currently am writing angular directives that can be used in a web app(html) as reusable web components. In angular modules& directives I have defined the dependency with require JS. In the html page if few dependencies say angular JS, Jquery are already loaded does it get recognized by the require JS framework in directives.

The directives can come from different JS, is it possible to load even require JS only once.

Any suggestion to achieve loading JS files only once is appreciated

Thanks
Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS does not know about anything else than what it itself loads. If a `script` element loads jQuery, and then a RequireJS module requires the module `jquery`, then RequireJS will try to load jQuery again. It won't test for the existence of a jQuery loaded with a `script` element before RequireJS was loaded.

This being said, *you* can write code to handle such scenario. For instance, the configuration you give to RequireJS could check whether `jQuery` is already defined:

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
    require.config({
        paths: {
            jquery: ...path/to/a/cdn/or/a/local/copy...
        }
    });
}
else {
    define('jquery', [], function () { return jQuery; });
}
```

The `true` branch of the `if` is for when jQuery has not been loaded. It configures RequireJS to find it. The `false` branch defines a `jquery` module that merely returns the `jQuery` global so that RequireJS does not actually load jQuery anew.

You should be able to perform a similar test for Angular. Remember that `require.config` can be called multiple times and RequireJS will combine the values passed in multiple calls.